# Animation is playing for me and me only when i have the tool out that plays the animation, I want it to work for everyone

Tags: animation, lua, roblox

So me and my freind are making a game in roblox studio and I made this animation for throwing a brick, well anyway i made a script for loading in the animation:

```
local function loadThrowAnimation() local animation_id = 13261407426

-- create a new Animation object in ReplicatedStorage
local replicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local animation = Instance.new("Animation")
animation.AnimationId = "rbxassetid://" .. animation_id
animation.Name = "Throw"
animation.Parent = replicatedStorage
print(animation:IsDescendantOf(replicatedStorage))

return animation

end

return loadThrowAnimation
```

i call this moduleScript in ServerScriptService so it runs first, then the script that actually plays the animation is this:

```
local tool = script.Parent

local animation_speed = 1

-- create a RemoteEvent object in ReplicatedStorage local replicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage") local remoteEvent = replicatedStorage:WaitForChild("PlayAnimation")

repeat wait() humanoid = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer.Character:FindFirstChildOfClass("Humanoid") until humanoid print(humanoid)

-- load the animation from ReplicatedStorage local animation = replicatedStorage.Throw local animationTrack = humanoid:LoadAnimation(animation) print(animationTrack)

local mouse = game.Players.LocalPlayer:GetMouse() local connection = nil

tool.Equipped:Connect(function() connection = mouse.Button1Down:Connect(function() print("M1 Clicked") local character = tool.Parent local humanoid = character:FindFirstChildOfClass("Humanoid") if humanoid then -- trigger the remote event to play the animation on all clients remoteEvent:FireServer() animationTrack.Priority = Enum.AnimationPriority.Action animationTrack:Play() print("Aimation if hit!") else warn("Humanoid not found in character hierarchy.") end end) end)

tool.Unequipped:Connect(function() if connection then connection:Disconnect() connection = nil end end)
```

which plays the animation when you have the brick tool out and when you click, and this works for me perfectly no errors or anything but when my freind trys this nothing happens, this is a LocalScript stored in a tool object in starterPack

this is my remote event script:

```
local replicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")

-- create a RemoteEvent object in ReplicatedStorage
local remoteEvent = Instance.new("RemoteEvent")
remoteEvent.Name = "PlayAnimation"
remoteEvent.Parent = replicatedStorage


-- listen to the remote event and play the animation on all clients
remoteEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player)
    local character = player.Character
    if character then
        local humanoid = character:FindFirstChildOfClass("Humanoid")
        if humanoid then
            local animation = replicatedStorage.Throw
            print("Server script runs")
            local animationTrack = humanoid:LoadAnimation(animation)
            animationTrack:Play()
        end
    end
end)
```

This is just a normal script stored in  ServerScriptService, yea im new to roblox studios code and roblox studio in general. Thanks in advance

I mostly tried moving the scripts around to see if that would change it, Its strange it works for me perfectly but it wont play for him, he gets all of the print statments in the output just no animation.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using RemoteEvent for this action.